# Displaying array of objects using map in reactJs

Tags: arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, mapping

I have 10 Array of objects like this:

[image: Array of Objects]

I tried to map `ingedients` and display the text:

```
    <ul>
        {this.props.data.ingredients.map(function(ingredient,i) { 
        return (<li key={i} item={ingredient}/>)
        })}
   </ul>
```

I get the result of ten bullets but the text is not being displayed. If I try ingredient.text , it says cannot display text of null.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting item prop with ingredient here.

```
return (<li key={i} item={ingredient}/>)
```

Where you probably want to display the text in the `li`, like this:

```
<ul>
    {this.props.data.ingredients.map(function(ingredient,i) { 
        return (<li key={i} item={ingredient}>{ingredient.text}</li>
    })}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. Tried it and i got a error TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of null.The value of text is a String

Comment: I made a code sandbox and it works. Take a look https://codesandbox.io/s/j7w9mrokyw

Comment: Thank you, that works great. It was simple mistake made in my end.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do the same in ES6 way

```
let ingredientsText = [];

{this.props.data.ingredients.map((ingredient,i) => { 
   ingredientsText.push(<li key={i} item={ingredient}>{ingredient.text}</li>);
})}

<ul>
    {ingredientsText}
</ul>
```